# Scrollable Tabs + Swiping for Lot of Input

Tags: android, view, input, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I'm working on an app where user should fill lot's of input fields and send that information to the server.

My Question is, is it a good way to design app with Scrollable Tabs + Swiping ?

I don't know exactly how many tabs there'll be, on all these tabs there should be some input types and at last when everything will be filled and the user clicks some button, i should get all the info from all these tabs.

So is using this design is a good way for implementing it ? or if not what's the better approach ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So much here depends on the kind of app and amount of information.  For example, in a 'business' app you aren't struggling to keep your users attention like in a game etc.  Also if there are many tabs to fill out all at once your users may get lost between pages.  In which case you might do better to control the users navigation through the tabs, rather than allowing them to skip all over the place, still using the tabbed 'look' as a quick visual check of how far through data entry they are.  This means you can validate as you go and avoid frustrating 'go back to page 1' messages for the user.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, but right now i'm not interested in Users side. I want to know how good and manageable this design will be for information gathering and so on . . .